# Lexer is not failing with runtime exception for bad input

Tags: antlr4, lexer

While upgrading from ANTLR 4.6 to 4.9.2, we have noticed changed in parser behavior and some text which earlier didn't used to be matched gets matched with no change in grammar.

Some Negative input cases are working with lexer
for example

```
title eq "Emplyee" 1234
```

I have overridden sytaxError using

```
lexer.addErrorListener(new BaseErrorListener()  {
    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

On debugging found that Lexer is not failing with runtime exception for bad input.

We use Java for this implementation.

The grammar:

```
grammar Filter;

start
 : appfilter
 ; 

appfilter
 : LBRACE appfilter RBRACE
 | negate LBRACE appfilter RBRACE
 | appfilter logical appfilter
 | simpleFilter
 | complexFilter
 ; 

complexFilter
 : key LSQBRACE appfilter RSQBRACE
 | key LSQBRACE appfilter RSQBRACE DOT_SEPARATOR simpleFilter
 ; 

simpleFilter
 : key binary value
 | key unary
 ; 

key
 : PATH
 | ATTRIBUTE
 ;

binary  : EQ; 
unary   : PR; 
logical : AND | OR; 
negate  : NOT;

EQ      : 'eq' | 'EQ' | 'Eq' | 'eQ'; 
PR      : 'pr' | 'PR' | 'Pr' | 'pR'; 
NOT     : 'not'; 
AND     : 'and'; 
OR      : 'or';
```

Comment: Can you provide the grammar?

Comment: grammar Filter;
start : appfilter;
appfilter : LBRACE appfilter RBRACE
 | negate LBRACE appfilter RBRACE
 | appfilter logical appfilter
 | simpleFilter
 | complexFilter;
complexFilter : key LSQBRACE appfilter RSQBRACE
 | key LSQBRACE appfilter RSQBRACE DOT_SEPARATOR simpleFilter
;
simpleFilter : key binary value
 | key unary
;
key : PATH
 | ATTRIBUTE
;
binary : EQ; 
unary : PR;
logical : AND | OR;
negate : NOT;
EQ : 'eq' | 'EQ' | 'Eq' | 'eQ';
PR : 'pr' | 'PR' | 'Pr' | 'pR';

NOT : 'not'; 
AND : 'and';
OR : 'or';

Comment: Come on, the grammar doesn't even pass the Antlr4 tool. (1) `value` is undefined. (2) LBRACE, RBRACE, LSQBRACE, RSQBRACE, DOT_SEPARATOR, PATH and ATTRIBUTE are all undefined, but the grammar will pass the Antlr tool if one corrects issue "(1)". (3) There aren't any rules to lex a string, e.g., `"Emplyee"`, which is in your input. I assume that's what `value` is for. (4) There's no whitespace skip or off-channel shunting. (5) There's no EOF-augmented rule so that "start" consumes all input. Consequently, the parse will likely return a valid parse up to "1234", correcting (1) through (4).

Comment: @user2986469 please move the grammar from the comment to the question. It's unreadable.